# Game server in Haskell

Tags: haskell, network-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm using `Network` and `Gloss` for a game server in Haskell. It works fine, except that the client has to close for the server to receive the data it sent. I bet it's a case of laziness...

Minimalist server:

```
import Network
import System.IO

main = do
    sock <- listenOn (PortNumber (fromIntegral 12345))
    loop sock

loop sock = do
    (hIn, _, _) <- accept sock
    str <- hGetContents hIn
    print str
    loop sock
```

Minimalist client:

```
import Network
import System.IO
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game

main = playIO
    (InWindow "Test Multi" (500, 500) (500, 500))
    white
    60
    Nothing
    draw
    (\_ x -> return x)
    advance

draw Nothing = return blank
draw (Just x) = return (Text (show x))

advance _ Nothing = do
    hOut <- connectTo "000.000.0.0" (PortNumber (fromIntegral 12345))
    hSetBuffering hOut NoBuffering
    hPutStr hOut "Hello!"
    return (Just hOut)
advance _ x = return x
```

I start the server, wait 10 seconds, then start the client, wait 15 seconds, see that nothing happens on the server, closes the client, see "Hello!" suddenly appear on the server.
I would like "Hello!" to appear while the client is running, in an `advance` call, otherwise I can't make a multiplayer game (sob)!

---

However, if I change the client's code to

```
main = loop Nothing
loop x = do
    x' <- advance 0 x
    getLine
```

the sever immediatly shows "Hello!" while the client is waiting for my input.

---

I tried, as suggested in another question, to use bang patterns and `hClose`:

```
-- ...
!str <- hGetContents hIn
hClose hIn
-- ...
```

which makes the output appear immediatly, without the client closing. That's great. But, I plan to use bytestrings because the data I send to the server is serialized, so I `import qualified Data.ByteString as B` and change `hGetContents` to `B.hGetContents`, which makes the problem re-appear.

---

The problem was indeed a case of laziness. `hGetContents` reads lazily all the contents of the `Handle`, so it finishes only when it's closed, when the client aborts the connection. Instead, I used `hGetLine` that returns the content each time it encounters a `\n`, which I use as a `end-of-message` tag.

Comment: Does this, perhaps, have to do with the playIO function? I am able to get the server to echo the client's message when I remove the drawing code, however, there is a delay of several seconds.

Comment: That's what I think as well. More precisely, client code using recursion have this issue, while the code I added in the question, using `getLine` works fine.

Comment: Even if I rewrite `draw` into `draw _ = return Blank` and wait 30 seconds (while writing this message :P), "Hello!" isn't written until I close. I wrote `draw` this way so we could really see that the connection to the server succeeded.

Comment: This is a duplicate, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373883/haskell-laziness-how-do-i-force-the-io-to-happen-sooner/5374132#5374132

Comment: You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: Your edit says you switched to using another `hGetContents` - why?  Don't use `hGetContents`!  How about `hGetSome`?

Comment: I now use `B.hGetLine`, because `encode` from Data.Serializable uses bytestrings and because the function, unlike `hGetContents` doesn't read the entire `Handle`, but wait for `\n` which I use as a "end-of-message" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be completely wrong, but isn't the problem  hGetContents? Surely that should wait till the *entire* contents sent through your socket have arrived before the next line (print...) starts. hGetContents is *designed* to give you all the contents sent until the socket is closed. Something like hGetLine could terminate straight away and you can leave the socket open to send more data through later. Your client could then use a hPutStrLn instead of hPutStr.

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:hGetContents). (Btw. I know `System.IO`'s `hGetContents` is being used here but its documentation is not clear.)

Comment: `hPutStrLn` got the same result. It isn't necessary since I used `hSetBuffering hOut NoBuffering` and it would add a `\n` that I don't need, because I'll use `encode` and `decode` when this works.

Comment: My main point was that you should try replacing hGetContents with hGetLine *in the server*. (The hPutStrLn is just to mirror the hGetLine.). I believe the server will then stop waiting until the socket is closed, but will print what it receives line by line.

Comment: If you don't want to use `'\n'` to signal to your server it should start processing, I think you'll need to use hPut and hGet, but I still don't think hGetContents is what you mean.

Comment: It's possible `hGetContents` isn't appropriate. It's fine if I use a bang pattern and close the handle, but I've just discovered I can keep the handle and get new data from the client. I should think of a way to stop reading; `hGetLine` is not bad.

Answer (score 3):

It defaults to line-buffered output, which is why `hPutStr` (which doesn't provide a line ending) doesn't output anything until you flush the buffer.  There are two ways you can solve this:

a) Call `hFlush stdout` manually any time you want to flush the output.

b) Use `hSetBuffering` to set the buffering to `NoBuffering`

All of those functions are found in the `System.IO` module.

Edit: Never mind, I just saw where you did that in the client.  I retract my answer with apologies.

Comment: In the client, I already have `hSetBuffering hOut NoBuffering`. I tried to put it as well in the server, before `str <- hGetContents hIn`, and I put `hFlush stdout` after it, but it's still the same. Edit: It's fine; you made me discover `hFlush` :).

Comment: @L01man Actually, try calling `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` in your server's `main` and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing changed. I tried another client program and I'm pretty sure it's the guilty part. I added some code in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you need to disable [algorithm Nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).
Try this code:

```
import Network.Socket

setSocketOption sock NoDelay 1
```

Comment: Maybe not relevant to the OP. But this got me past a bug I've been stuck on for two days!  Thanks for the pointer.