# haskell hFlush isn't working the way Im expecting

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to get a program to read an entire file using hFlush, in order to avoid an issue I'm having which has to do with the lazy IO.

```
readHandle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
hSetBuffering readHandle $ BlockBuffering (Just 2048)
fileText <- hGetContents readHandle
hFlush readHandle
hClose readHandle
```

This just gives me the error: hFlush: illegal operation (handle is closed)

could somebody help me understand what is going on

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373883/haskell-laziness-how-do-i-force-the-io-to-happen-sooner?rq=1

Comment: Also, `hFlush` flushes the _output_ buffer. It doesn't make any sense to use it on a read-only handle in the first place.

Comment: I recommend using `hGetContents` from `System.IO.Strict` and avoid using lazy IO altogether.

Answer (score 6):

Your expectation is wrong.  In general, except for explicitly closing a handle, you shoudn't use a handle after an `hGetContents` call.  From the haddock:

> Computation `hGetContents hdl` returns the list of characters
>   corresponding to the unread portion of the channel or file managed by
>   hdl, which is put into an intermediate state, semi-closed. In this
>   state, hdl is effectively closed, but items are read from hdl on
>   demand and accumulated in a special list returned by `hGetContents hdl`.